# If a person plays game of sex, is it same as adultery?

Tags: sex, game

Is playing game with sex same as commiting adultery, there was a game I used to play which had anal sex and I used to play it, so am I accountable for that sin even though I am sure I will try my best not to do that in real life, and another question is anak sex kufr?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. You've asked multiple questions in one post each of them already are covered on the site please stick to one question per post.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is adultery. But adultery has different levels. Just like there are major and minor sins.

> Abu Huraira reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying. The **adultery
> of the eye** is the lustful look and the **adultery of the ears** is
> listening to voluptuous (song or talk) and the **adultery of the
> tongue** is licentious speech and the **adultery of the hand** is the
> lustful grip (embrace) and the **adultery of the feet** is to walk (to
> the place) where he intends to commit adultery and the heart yearns
> and desires which he **may or may not put into effect**.
>
> Sahih Muslim 2658

Here is another evidence. Clear command ordering muslims to not look at forbidden things.

> “Tell the believing men to lower their gaze (from looking at forbidden
> things).” (24:30)

Answering your last part of the question: This is not from the actions of Kufr. Major sins do not take anyone outside the fold of Islam unless he/she commits shirk.